# Memory management using bit maps vs linked list

Tags: memory, memory-management, linked-list, operating-system

There are two ways of doing memory management: using bits, and using linked list. 
While using bits, we maintain a bit map of size equal to number of allocation units
While using liked list, we maintain two linked lists: one for allocated memory, and one for holes

can somebody help me identify the pros and cons of these two methods, and when we should prefer on over the other. I have understood both the methods, but cannot identify the situation when I will prefer one over the other.

To further clarify, these both techniques are standard techniques used in operating systems books.

Comment: How about thinking about the two structures in the context? E.g. if you need to allocate, what do you do using each method, how easy is it to do, how fast, how scalable is it? Then think of each structure itself. How much memory do you need for each, given the total of N bytes of memory in the system? Then think if you can make improvements, speed up the search for holes, for example. It's not very difficult, just start putting things into the right context.

Answer (score 3):

**Linked list**

pros: Small space requirements, as each block can store a pointer to the next free block.

cons: To traverse the list, you need to read each block! Also, it is costly to maintain the list in a "contiguous" manner, in order to avoid fragmentation (think about the cost of updating the list in a smarter way than just appending each new free block at the end).

The linked list scheme can be made slightly more efficient by storing multiple free blocks ID in each block (thus fewer I/Os are required to retrieve some amount of free blocks).

**Bitmap**

pros: Random allocation: checking if a block is free only requires reading the corresponding bit; also, checking for a large continuous section is relatively fast (as you can check a word size of bits from the bitmap in a single read). Fast deletion: you can just flip a bit to "free" a block, without overwriting the data.

cons: Higher memory requirements, as you need one bit per block (~128MB for a 1TB disk with 1KB blocks).

**Trade off**

If the disk is almost full, it might make sense to use a linked list, as it will need less blocks than the bitmap. However, most of the time the bitmap will be store in main memory, which will make it more efficient than the linked list. I guess that if the disk is almost full, and you can store the linked list in main memory, then it's a good alternative too.

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_space_bitmap

Comment: it's also worth mentioning that the cons for a bitmap are frequently irrelevant. 128 MB per 1 TB isn't typically of concern unless you are working under whacko circumstances